# Nest API - FirebaseError: Too many requests

Tags: nest-api

I've been looking through the Nest API, but I can't seem to find what "Too many requests" really means. What is too many? Is 5 requests per minute too many? 50 requests per minute too many? Is it too many requests per client? Too many requests per thermostat? Too many requests per home.nest.com account? After reaching the limit, how long until I can successfully make a request?

Any information or experiences will be extremely useful. Thanks!

This is what I'm getting...

```
protected void setHighTemp(int value){
    fb.child("target_temperature_high_f").setValue(value, new CompletionListener() {
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError arg0, Firebase arg1) {
            System.out.println("Communicaiton error: " + arg0);
        }
    });
```

Output: Communicaiton error: FirebaseError: Too many requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant documentation for rate limits is at https://developer.nest.com/documentation/data-rate-limits

It looks like you're hitting the per device/structure limit which is described as

> Every write to the data model requires the device to wake up and synchronize state. This drains the battery, so we limit the number of writes to devices and structures. We also monitor the battery state of all devices. If they drop below a certain threshold we will reject write requests until the battery has recharged.

Can you tell us how you're using the API?

-- Nagesh

Comment: Thanks. We are adding nest as a new integration into our Home Automation product. We run a central server (so only one client) and are using Firebase for the API calls.

Comment: Has nest published anything a little more specific regarding limits, or is there anything that you tell me based on your experience? For example, at what point can we expect to hit these different rate limits? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Nageh says nest does have limited the requests for certain time period to avoid the battery drainage. the Nest api still doesn't say the limit or the number of requests per time pariod or anything of that sort.

Comment: Are you running into the same problem? What has your experience been? I'm learning that there must be some sort of sliding scale algorithm in action. In the beginning of development, I was able to make changes much more rapidly and consistently than I can now. Once I had my first command rejection, it seems like my rate limit kept getting tighter and tighter. I can now do maybe 3-5 changes in a row before hitting a limit.

Comment: @jesse how frequent can you make your 3-5 changes?